# Asynctask getting stuck

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I am trying to develop an Android application. Every time when application starts, it has to fetch some details from a server. I have used an `asynctask` for it and I am calling it in the `onCreate` method in android. It works perfectly when the server is running and but when the server is not running I don't want my application to get hang waiting for a time out and finding out that the server is not running. What is a better way to implement ? In my present method the application is stuck till the time out is happening.

Comment: Add a timeout to the connection? If you are using an AsyncTask, your application shouldn't freeze. Edit the question to show code

Comment: Use volley library, It will handle it.

Comment: Why is it stuck if it is an asynctask? Do you call the "get" on the asynctask in the oncreate?(it will then wait for the task and be stuck)   If so avoid that, and do it in onPostExecute

Comment: @LuukGrefte I was using `asyncTask.execute().get();`  when I changed to  `asyncTask.execute()` It works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using `asyncTask.execute().get();` when I changed to `asyncTask.execute()` It works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timout to the `HttpURLConnection` by using the following code

```
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
```

Full source code is given below. cheers :)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

             @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              new Test().execute();
             }


             //AsyncTask 
             class Test extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

              @Override
              protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
               InputStream in = null;
               String queryResult = "";
               URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
               HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)          url.openConnection();

              //add parameters
              urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
              urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
              urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
              urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
              urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));
               try {
            //write OutputStream
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


                InputStream in = new     BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                queryResult = readStream( in );
               } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
               }
               return queryResult;

              }
              private String readStream(InputStream iStream) throws IOException {

               //Buffered reader allows us to read line by line
               try (BufferedReader bReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream))) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till end
                 builder.append(line);
                }
                return builder.toString();
               }
              }
            private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws   UnsupportedEncodingException
            {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;

                for (NameValuePair pair : params)
                {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        result.append("&");

                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
                    result.append("=");
                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }

                return result.toString();
            }
              protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
               // do further things 
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               toast.show();

              }

             }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below line of code for it once:

```
 try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1");   
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        urlc.connect();
        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {    
        // condition for connection is fine , 200 = "OK" 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
```